# Upload images into a file server and store the url to the image using nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, ng2-file-upload

I am implementing a web app using `MEAN Stack` and `Angular 6`. There I want to submit a form with file upload. `'.png'` files should be uploaded.

I want to save the file in a different file server and send the url to the image.Currently I upload files into a folder in my project and save the image in db (I used `ng2fileupload` and `multer` for that.). Then it saves like this.

```
"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAV4AAAFUCAYAAABssFR8AAAK..."
```

But I want to save the image url and the image should be retrived by the url. Does anyone can explain a proper method for that?

Comment: you can use Cloudinary services

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a month ago and find out a solution to this problem. Though I haven't used `multer` in the app.

1. From my frontend, I will be sending an object to Node API endpoint `/event` which will look like:-

`let img = {
   content: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg...",
   filename: 'yourfile.png'
}`

2. At the backend, I'm using [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/) to store my images (Its free plan allows 10GB storage) and returns secure **https** URLs. So install it using `npm i cloudinary` and require in your `api.js` file.
   And add the below configuration

   `cloudinary.config({
       cloud_name: 'yourapp',
       api_key: 'YOUR_KEY',
       api_secret: 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY'
   });`

**Last Step**:- (Not so optimized code)

Let say I have an **event Schema** which has images array, where I'll be storing the URLs returned by cloudinary.

```
app.post('/event', (req, res) => {
    try {
        if (req.body.images.length > 0) {

           // Creating new Event instance

            const event = new Event({
                images: [],
            });

           // Looping over every image coming in the request object from frontend
            req.body.images.forEach((img) => {
                const base64Data = img.content.split(',')[1];

            // Writing the images in upload folder for time being 
                fs.writeFileSync(`./uploads/${img.filename}`, base64Data, 'base64', (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw err;
                    }
                });

              /* Now that image is saved in upload folder, Cloudnary picks 
             the image from upload folder and store it at their cloud space.*/
                cloudinary.uploader.upload(`./uploads/${img.filename}`, async (result) => {

                 // Cloudnary returns id & URL of the image which is pushed into the event.images array.
                    event.images.push({
                        id: result.public_id,
                        url: result.secure_url
                    });

                 // Once image is pushed into the array, I'm removing it from my server's upload folder using unlinkSync function
                    fs.unlinkSync(`./uploads/${img.filename}`);

       // When all the images are uploaded then I'm sending back the response
                    if (req.body.images.length === event.images.length) {
                        await event.save();
                        res.send({
                            event,
                            msg: 'Event created successfully'
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(400).send(e);
    }
});
```

**P.S.** Go ahead and suggest some optimization solution for this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588060/upload-images-for-an-event-using-cloudinary-api)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I noticed that we can retrieve the file path by multer object. Updated the new question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53099208/retrieve-file-path-from-multer-object-and-save-in-mongodb-using-nodejs-and-ang